# How do I redirect a javaw.exe console output to a log file?

Tags: java, console, log4j

I am wanting to start my Java program from a batch file.  This is the script I want to use to start the app but the problem is that I am not able to get the console output to redirect to a log file.   Can anyone offer any hints without having to edit any code, and by using Java command line options or something?

```
@echo off
set TASK=MyApp
TITLE %TASK%
start javaw.exe -cp .;Server.jar;Util.jar com.manage.Program %1 > log.log 2>&1
taskkill /T /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %TASK%"
```

So, the above works, and actually kills the cmd window that spawns my Swing app, but it doesn't log anything to the log file, presumably because the "start" forked the process away from the "> log.log 2>&1" arg?

I could probably fix it by using start to call another batch file but I am hoping for a more elegant answer.

Comment: as you can see, i am trying to start the Swing application with console in the background so that the swing application exists only on its own to the user.   i need to be able to see errors though, if they occur, which is why i am hoping for a way to output to a log file, if possible.

Comment: Right now I am exploring if there is a way that I can reference log4j and then have it default to diverting console output to file? (without editing any java code of course, which makes this a actual question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to log console output without actually displaying a console. I can see three ways of doing something similar:

1. Start console minimized, so that it's less annoying. You can do that by creating a shortcut to a batch file, and then setting the properties of the shortcut to run the batch file in a minimized window instead of using the default setting of "Normal window".
2. Create a script to run the bat file in a hidden window, like so: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/8bbed56f-a7aa-491f-a296-687dd96098a3
3. Use a third party tool, like [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html). (Note: according to djangofan, hstart was not written for Java programs and does not really work)

Comment: great suggestions.  im wrestling with getting hstart to work properly but the question period is about to end and i am forced to pick you as the best answer.

Comment: just as a note, hstart  didn't really work.  it wasn't designed for Java programs.

Comment: Option 2 seems like my only viable option. As someone who's never coded in VB, how do I change that script to run, say, `test.bat` in the same directory as the script, instead of Notepad++?

Answer (score 7):

Its more simple than you think.

You only need to change the `System.out`:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("log.txt",true)));
```

And that's it!

Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know using javaw suppresses all System.out.println(...) to the console.

Therefore your application needs to implement logging internally. You could use a wrapper class to redirect the output using System.setOut(...) to write to a file. Then your wrapper class would invoke you other class.

Comment: as a QA person I can have the developer do this but I'd rather find a solution that I can solve without bugging development.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes your webstart application crashes and you cannot see why because the Console closes with the crash.
To enable console logging in Java webstart with JDK 1.6:

Start->Run...->**javaws -viewer**
Close the Java Cache Viewer
**Advanced tab->Debugging**
check 'Enable tracing' and 'Enable logging'

You logfiles can now be found in:

**C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\log**

Comment: Note with newer Windows version the log files can be found in C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't get why you said as a comment to Eugene Kuleshov that even java.exe won't do it.

You have to be careful to redirect both out and err output streams.
Usually, when sending data to the console output in Java, the "normal" console log is sent to `System.out` but errors are sent to `System.err`. The DOS cmd handles this with two different streams.
In this case, you have to either redirect the error stream to a different file like this

```
java.exe -cp .;Server.jar;Util.jar com.manage.Program %1 > log.log 2> err.log
```

or you can merge it in the same file by doing

```
java.exe -cp .;Server.jar;Util.jar com.manage.Program %1 > log.log 2>&1
```

We have the same issue when using the `start javaw` command.
We only use it in production and use the above java.exe when on test bench.

Of course, the best way would be not to output to the console which is the best practice, but who's doing this? ;)

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful but didn't quite answer my question.  Maybe there is no answer?  Maybe it can't be done?

Comment: I found another workaround, based on your suggestion:  https://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and

Comment: @djangofan You will have to use java.exe instead of javaw.exe which will launch another process, the first one, terminating, will not produce any log.

Answer (score 2):

You should use java.exe instead of javaw.exe

Comment: If I use 'call java.exe'  OR  'call javaw.exe' I get the exact same behavior actually, that it actually can log to file.  My question is about being able to fork the process from the batch file so that the cmd window can be closed, but MOST IMPORTANTLY, the console can be still logged to file.   Javaw.exe  seems to be able to redirect to file as easily as Java.exe fi you use the DOS 'call' instead of 'start'.  So, in other words, I want to be able to redirect the console of the forked process.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need in the batch file

start /b javaw.exe -cp .;Server.jar;Util.jar com.manage.Program %1 > log.log 2>&1

don't put any of the other information in there. Once your program exits check the log file.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.exe something.bat > console_output.txt
```

I think this will work.

Comment: awesome guess.  I tried various ways of using your idea but it didnt work.   the cmd.exe shell comes up and it freezes and does nothing... neither does the javaw.exe process start.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
`JRE\bin\java -cp .;Server.jar;Util.jar com.manage.Program >>log.log`
or
`JRE\bin\javaw -cp .;Server.jar;Util.jar com.manage.Program >>log.log`

save the above as a batch file and run.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked perfectly fine for me without changing a single line of code in my java application.

`javaw -jar <jar_file>.jar >> <log_file>.log`

Sorry, I am not allowed to put a comment on Vanchinathan's post, so posting an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command line at cmd

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin>javaw -jar D:\ccr_notification\ccr-api-0.
0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 2>&1 >D:\ccr_notification\output.log`

Reference
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with the command below

start /B /I javaw -jar program.jar >> output.log

Don't know if it will help someone...