# Check if HTTP port is open on Windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file, tomcat

I'm trying to check if Tomcat is ready after running jar file. I found this code on StackOverflow and I want to write Windows bash equivalent code.

my idea is to  log in file and check each 10 secondes in the log file for a sentence that appears when tomcat finish loading

this is my code :

```
@echo off
start javaw -jar ICAPS_DASHBOARD-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  1>> log.txt
::loop will be here
 findstr /m "Started IcapsDashboardApplication"  log.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo There is hope!
goto fin
)
echo no hope
:fin
echo fin
pause >nul
```

but I get nothing in the log file
and if I do

```
javaw -jar ICAPS_DASHBOARD-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  1>> log.txt
```

he don't run  commands below.
thanks

Comment: SO is not a free translation service. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what particular problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: You are maybe right I will try to add some code, :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers can you see this edit please

Comment: So, your question is _not_, how to test for an open port now? Would be great if you think about what you want to achive, before you begin.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4464319/1630171).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function (credits go to Tobias Weltner, as far as I remember):

```
function Test-NetworkPort
{
    param
    (
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [int32[]]
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $Port = $(137..139 + 443 + 445),
        [int32]
        $Timeout=1000,
        [switch]
        $AllResults
    )
    process
    {
        $count = 0
        ForEach ($PortNumber in $Port)
        {
            $count ++
            $perc = $count * 100 / $Port.Count
            Write-Progress -Activity "Scanning on \\$ComputerName" -Status "Port $PortNumber" -PercentComplete $perc
            # in PowerShell 2.0 muss [Ordered] entfernt werden
            # dann ist die Reihenfolge der Eigenschaften aber zufällig.
            $result = New-Object PSObject -Property ([Ordered]@{
                Port="$PortNumber"
                Open=$False
                Type='TCP'
                ComputerName=$ComputerName
                })
            $TCPClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
            $Connection = $TCPClient.BeginConnect($ComputerName, $PortNumber, $null, $null)
            try
            {
                if ($Connection.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($Timeout, $false))
                {
                    $null = $TCPClient.EndConnect($Connection)
                    $result.Open = $true
                }
            }
            catch {} 
    finally { $TCPClient.Close() }
            $result | Where-Object { $AllResults -or $_.Open }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this `Test-NetworkPort -Computername Tomcat1 -Port 80, 8080, 443 -Allresults`

Remark: If using Powershell 2, you need to remove the word `[ordered` at line 24